# Using Bootstrap's Purple Theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to do some quick prototyping with Bootstrap and I'd like to use the purple theme that's in action [over on the Bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/), however I can't seem to find where the styles are hidden. For example, `.bs-docs-header` gets no styling by default. In fact, I can't even find styling for `.bs-docs-header` in any of the CSS.

This is how it looks over on the Bootstrap site:
[image]

And this is how it looks over on my site:
[image]

No idea where those styles are coming from, or aren't. Any help getting this to work would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's their own "custom" style. it customizes the default bootstrap theme and you ARE suppose to do that to give your own feel to your website

Comment: @DanielCheung I do understand this. This is just for quick bootstrapping so I can quickly build out a prototype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bootstrap site has a reference to `docs.min.css` which contains this:

```
.bs-docs-header {
    position: relative;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    color: #cdbfe3;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    background-color: #6f5499;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#563d7c),to(#6f5499));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#563d7c 0,#6f5499 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#563d7c 0,#6f5499 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#563d7c 0,#6f5499 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#563d7c', endColorstr='#6F5499', GradientType=0);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Weird. I wonder if those styles are being held back to encourage users to write their own styles. Would be helpful if these header classes were included.

Comment: Why? It's an additional style for their website. If you want a template to use, there's plenty of website offering that. Or if you want to use this purple one, you can download it and play with it. Looking at the source file, it is released under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License.

Comment: @DavidG OP specifically said *"the purple theme that's in action over on the Bootstrap site"*

Comment: @DanielCheung Like I said, he's free to download the CSS and use it, though (s)he will have to learn the classes involved.

Comment: @DavidG That's fair enough then. I thought all styling on that site was built with its own components. Understandable if some of it is custom.